# How to automate an installation of Phusion Passenger and Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, automation

When the command:

```
./passenger-install-nginx-module
```

is run, it asks a bunch of questions when logged in to the server.

The aim is to automate this process, how can this be done if it requires specific answers during the installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the version of Phusion Passenger, [it should ether be possible to do](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/fvd4KDJtru4)

```
yes | passenger-install-nginx-module
```

(for version **2.0.x**) or

```
passenger-install-nginx-module --auto
```

for versions greater than **2.1**.